# Thurston geometry from left invariant metric on $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

One of the eight Thurston geometry is $\widetilde{\operatorname{SL}}(2,\mathbb{R})$ the universal cover of the real special linear group in dimension $2$.

A standard way to construct its homogeneus metric is to see it as the universal cover of $\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})\cong\operatorname{Isom}^+(\mathbb{H}^2)$. This group acts transitively and freely on the unit tangent bundle of the hyperbolic plane $U\mathbb{H}^2$ hence, up to choosing a point, can be identified with it. But now on $U\mathbb{H}^2$ there is a standard Riemannian metric which arise by seeing the unit tangent bundle as a submanifold of the tangent bundle endowed with the Sasaki metric.

As pointed out in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115138/natural-metric-on-tangent-bundle-of-hyperbolic-plane) this construction indeed corresponds to the choice of a left-invariant metric on $\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, which can be built by choosing an appropriate inner product  $g_e$ on $T_e\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

**My question is:** which explicit inner product on $T_e\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ gives rise to the left-infariant metric correspinding to the Sasaki metric on the unit bundle $U\mathbb{H}^2$?

Comment: Thurston does not specify a metric. For him, a geometry is determined by a Lie group and a space it acts on.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for pointing that out... so when the unit bundle construction is given we are in fact giving just an example of that geometry? I feel like I'm missing something very basic here...

Comment: You have to decide on what you mean by "geometry." If you mean in Thurston's sense, then yes, this gives you one of 8 geometries. If you mean in metric sense, then you need an extra data (metric or/and connection on the bundle).

Comment: Ok thank you! then it think the question of how to represent the Sasaki metric on the tnagent bundle as a left invariant metric on a lie group still makes sense.. I fixed the question